# Set Java path in command line for only one directory

Tags: java, command-line, command-prompt

I am running a program that utilizes Scala 2.10 for work and is not compatible with Java 8, only Java 7. In a Windows 7 command line, how can I set the java path to use Java 7 ONLY for that directory?

Comment: I don't believe that windows allows you to have per-folder environment variables.  Why not make a .bat file which sets JAVA_HOME and then runs your program?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If the program uses a batch to start, then add this line before the start of the program:

```
SET JAVA_HOME="C:\Program Files\Java7\Java.exe"
```

(This is just an example, the directory might be different on your computer)

If the program does not use such a batch (you can recognize it because it ends with either .cmd or .bat) create such a file and use that for launching the program instead:

```
@echo off
SET JAVA_HOME=...
ThisIsMyFancyScalaProgram.Exe
```

Answer (score 8):

You may create 2 batch file one for java 7 and one for java 8 like this -

**jdk7.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Setting JAVA_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11
echo setting PATH
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.0_11\bin;%PATH%
echo Display java version
java -version
```

**jdk8.bat**

```
@echo off
echo Setting JAVA_HOME
set JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_11
echo setting PATH
set PATH=C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.7.8_11\bin;%PATH%
echo Display java version
java -version
```

You may quickly switch between them running these batch file.

Answer (score 0):

**To Add system environment variables**:

```
setx JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"

setx PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";
```

**To update system environment variables:**

```
setx -m JAVA_HOME "C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0"

setx -m PATH "%PATH%;%JAVA_HOME%\bin";
```

Comment: Where is the improvement over Razibs answer ?